# RXJS Action not firing on iOS

Tags: rxjs

I've got a very bizarre issue with this epic. It's working fine on desktop, android but not working at all on iOS.. well it never picks up the action. I'm sure the action is being fired (but I've not got redux dev tools remote to work yet to confirm)

```
export function authenticate(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(USER_LOGIN)
    .mergeMap(({email, password}) => login(email, password)
        .map(res => {
          console.log(res)
          if (res.error) {
            return { type: AUTH_FAILED, payload: res.message }
          } else {
            return { type: AUTH_SUCCESS, payload: res.payload }
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Login error: ', err)
          return { type: AUTH_FAILED, message: err }
        })
    )
}
```

The action is being fired in

```
function selectorFactory(dispatch) {
  return state => ({
...
    login: (email,password) => dispatch(userLogin(email,password)),
...
}
```

I've console logged this as working, we're getting to the dispatch, but that epic is not firing.. any clues?

Comment: Remove catch and post the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Caused by an error elsewhere that was very hard to debug.